# Energy power relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, power

If we have an energy equation like
$E=A\sin(wt-kx)$
If we differentiate it w.r.t. time, we will get power.
If we again differentiate the last equation, it will be termed as power per unit time.
But what it will represent and what is it's significance?

Comment: Well I think you can differentiate it again and still we will get a question “What does this represent “?

Comment: The rate of change of power wrt time (i.e. if $\ddot{E}>0$, the power is increasing)? We might use such an expression for an optimisation problem.

Comment: Yes, it represents the rate at which the power is changing. I’m not sure why the previous comment has a question mark after stating this.

Comment: The time derivative of anything is simply its rate of change.

Answer (score 0):

> But what it will represent and what is it's significance?

It will represent how quickly your power is changing. A positive value indicates that the power is increasing and a negative value indicates that the power is decreasing. As far as I know it has no particular physical significance.